# Unable to redirect to client URL from server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, authentication, passport.js

I am currently building a React application which requires google login.
As I'm trying to build a server which can also later serve PWA, I'm planning on doing the authentication using JWT.

The problem that's occurring is that I'm not being able to redirect my app to the client URL from the server.

For example, suppose my client is running on localhost:8100 and the server is running on localhost:3100.
I have set up proxy on my react app to forward all request to /auth/* to the server.
After the auth is complete, when I try to redirect from my server to client using res.redirect("/handleAuth/$token"), I am being redirected to localhost:3000/handleAuth/$token instead of localhost:8100/handleAuth/$token

Here is the server code

```
const passport = require("passport");

passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
      {
        ...keys.google,
        callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback",
        proxy: true
      },
      async (accessToken, refreshToken, { _json }, done) => {
        done(null, _json);
      }
    )
  );

app.get(
    "/auth/google",
    passport.authenticate("google", {
      session: false,
      scope: ["openid", "profile", "email"]
    })
  );

  app.get(
    "/auth/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google", { session: false }),
    (req, res) => {
      const token= generateToken(req.user);

      // Redirecting to serverUrl/handleAuth/${token} instead of clientURL/handleAuth/${token}
      res.redirect(`/handleAuth/${token}`)
    }
  );
```

Since I'm using JWT, I haven't initialized session on the server.

If there is any approach where I'll be able to open another child window where login occurs and I can send the response as json which could read by the parent window, or any other way that can be also used by native android/ios apps which is more decent than this, then please share.

Comment: I recommend you refer this documentation http://www.passportjs.org/docs/downloads/html/ also many answers there already in stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=GoogleStrategy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found out what the problem was.
While setting proxy in react, set changeOrigin to false.
It used to work earlier with changeOrigin set to true, but now that it's changed, here's the fix.